# Why does this movie not load in IE when hosted on web?

Tags: html, video, loading

I create a simple video elements within an HTML page . Here the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            body{
                background:gray; 
                -webkit-touch-callout: none;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -khtml-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }
            #vid_container {position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;visibility:visible;text-align:center;z-index:501;}
            #vid_background {position:absolute;left:-350px;top:-270px;width:700px;height:540px;background:url(datas/vid_bg.png);z-index:501;}
            #vid_loader {position:absolute;left:-320px;top:-240px;text-align:center;z-index:502;}
            #vid_button {position:absolute;left:-346px;top:-266px;width:30px;height:30px;background:url(datas/vid_btn.png);z-index:503;cursor:pointer;}


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='vid_container'>

        <div id='vid_background'></div>

        <video id='vid_loader' width="640" height="480" preload controls>
            <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div id='vid_button'></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When i test the code in INTERNET EXPLORER on local (my computer) it works fine and the movie load . but when i host it in my FTP and test via internet , it doesn't load (where it loads on all other browsers)

You can test your self : (open this link with other browsers , it will work fine but with ie it's not )

http://ajnadeen-me.com/eBook/vidbug/index.html

The movie is MP4 compression H.264.

Thanks .

Comment: Which version of IE. As far as I know h264 is only working as of IE9 (I could be wrong though)...

Comment: Indeed , it's not working on IE9

Comment: ok here is a quick link about html 5 video. I think it will help you. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: thx naresh , when i test my code on the 'try yourself' from http://www.w3schools.com , it worked fine ... does this mean that the video that am using is involved ?

Comment: Well i am really confused now ... i jst copy the code from w3schools.com "test yourself" , and put in my index.html and jst changed the video link to mine ... ITs not loading on IE . but it works with there video on there Website ... means 2 OPtions :
1- The video Compression itself must be otherwise .
2- MAY be MY FTP HOST ????

Comment: I insist in your Web server configuration, I'll take a look when I have time

Comment: Thanks Axel , you were right , but my ignorance about the MIME and stuffs profide me to understand you as it should . Thanks dude . @Axel

Comment: If the advices you are receiving solve your problem, you should choose the answer that solves your question the more accurately and mark it as correct. You should also delete [one of your duplicate posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153629/video-loading-issues-with-internet-explorer-via-web-not-localy/14213078). By the way, I have duplicated m answer to both questions in case you delete this :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should make sure that the HTML5 tag `<video>` is supported by Internet Explorer. Only Internet explorer 9 supports it natively see [HERE](http://caniuse.com/#search=video), so if you want it to work also with prior versions you need to add the support of HTML5 tags to older versions of Internet Explorer.
If you haven't done it already, you can use [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). Just add this code in the `head` of your webpage:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Now you can use the `video` tag.
I give you a solution that uses the video html5 tag first and if that fails it loads the video by using a flash video player without need to use javascript or browser sniffing. Then if even that fails an image placeholder (poster) is displayed and you can allow the visitor of the website to download the video. If you aren't interested in the last part, you can just delete it from the code. As you see in the code, i suggest you to create the video not only in `mp4` format but also `ogg` and `webm`.

**Format compatibility**:

- Internet Explorer 9+ supports Mp4 but not WebM and Ogg.
- Chrome 6+ supports all the three formats.
- Firefox 3.6+ supports WebM and Ogg but doesn't support Mp4.
- Safari 5+ supports Mp4 but doesn't support WebM and Ogg.
- Opera 10.6+ supports WebM and Ogg but doesn't support Mp4.

That's why you should include all the three formats.

I removed the `preload` attribute because it isn't supported by Internet Explorer.

Here the **HTML** code is:

```
<video controls poster="poster.jpg" width="640" height="480">
    <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="my_video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="my_video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="480">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['poster.jpg',{'url':'my_video.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
        <img alt="Video" src="poster.jpg" width="640" height="480" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>
</video>
<p>
    <strong>Download video:</strong> <a href="my_video.mp4">MP4 format</a> | <a href="my_video.ogv">Ogg format</a> | <a href="my_video.webm">WebM format</a>
</p>
```

**Server support**:

If the MIME type isn't set correctly on the server you may not be able to play the video.
If you use Apache server you may add the extension of the video file in `/etc/apache` or via the `AddType` configuration directive in `httpd.conf` .

**For Ogg**:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
```

**For WebM**:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

**For Mp4**:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

---

I checked the example on w3schools with Internet Explorer 9. If i switch to Internet Explorer 7 or Internet Explorer 8 it isn't supported. (Because of the HTML5 video tag compatibility issue i talked about before). Again you could solve that by using htmlshiv.

It is possible that even if you use Internet Explorer 9, it displays the page in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (compatibility mode, that is as ie7 or ie8). You can avoid that by making sure to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` without any xml prolog.

Besides you could force the browser emulation to the latest version of Internet Explorer by adding this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

In the `head` of your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks Fabio for your time . But actually i haven't many option for the movie , since i just brough the main problem , but actually my problem is withing a bigger script (E-Book) that u can see [a Here](http://ajnadeen-me.com/eBook/Arab_Ebook_1.1.BETA/index.html)! 
Flash is forbidden by the customer , and loading the movie isn't allowed .

Comment: what is astonishing me is that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop)! it's working fine , i took the same code and paste in my page , it stills not loading ... so there's only 2 possibilities :
1- The video compression 
2- my FTP host (possible ? )
do you agree?
Or maybe something must be included in the Header since there we can't see the header.

Comment: Still not working dude, it's probably my FTP server ... thanks again buddy. Well i'll try to understand more about MIME and update what's going on . But tell me plz , this MIME issue can affect only IE ? and not the other browsers ?

Comment: the MIME issue can affect all browsers because the issue isn't related to the browser but to the server. hmm about you mentioning the ftp server..hmm it shouldn't be that.You said you see it with other browsers?Then it shouldn't be that problem.Otherwise it could be a caching issue on your pc or server-side.You could delete your cache and try again. Or it could be the server that uses caching in order to boost performance and you uploaded a previous version of the file and it didn't update to the new one.Do you know what type of server the website is using?I may also check it on my own else :)

Comment: Actually , this problem is happening 4 days ago , so the cach issues is out . and i don't know the type of the server website.  May i ask you soemthing Fabio ? if it's possible to send you the video that am using and so the code (via email, or can i link a zip here?) , and then you try (please) to host the page somewhere that have the correct MIME and stuffs . then if it works , the problem is my FTP server , if not , we both have the same problem : ) .

Comment: You are using a Windows hosting with server IIS version 7.0 :) So you don't use Apache. You could upload the files to a file hosting and i may download it and see a bit and if i figure out something i let you know. I prefer not sharing my email here for privacy/security reasons. @user1817826

Comment: By the way, i downloaded the movie from w3schools.com (video and the HTML content it self) , then upload it in ftp host ... same ISSUE , works on all browsers except the IE 9 ... Wich means one possibility stills : The FTP SERVER . please if you have time , try to download the w3schools.com html content + there movie (i can send it to you) , then try to host it somewhere , and test in IE 9 . if it works then my FTP server , if not  ==== Big problem to solve  :)

Ok i understand for the email , i'll give u download link soon . thx. (you should create a draft email for wiked strengers like m:)

Comment: Here's the [link](http://ajnadeen-me.com/eBook/index.html) . Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: I tried on my server with Internet Explorer 9 and it works for me @Sachou

Comment: Thanks dude ... hope i'll help one day ; ) . can you give me the link so i test ? @Fabio

Comment: for (i=0;i<9999;i++) { THANKS_FABIO();} @Fabio

Comment: However how can i choose a good webserver? You suggest me something?

Comment: for your next projects i suggest you Apache instead of IIS as a web server. For that you need a linux hosting. (don't worry, ftp will work the same way). Then apart from the type of server it depends on the hosting provider. I think you used a shared hosting, so the hosting company set up the server how she wants and doesnt let you change something if it doesn't work. If you develop many websites you may buy a vps or a dedicated server and host all your website on your own server so you have full control. Anyway it requires higher knowledge to manage it and it is expensive

Comment: so you can balance the cost only if you host many websites. If you really have many clients you may even be a reseller of the hosting company and even earn a percentage on each hosted domain :)

Comment: @Fabio: You mention, "That's why you should include all the three formats." - but from the compatibility table you posted it would seem that you only need two formats, since you state that... Mp4 is supported by IE9, Cr6+, Sf5+ and Ogg is supported by FF3.6+, Op10.6+ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your server doesn't have the correct MIME type set up for MP4 video. See point 2 in: [HTML5 Multimedia Troubleshooting](http://html5doctor.com/multimedia-troubleshooting/).

Comment: @user1817826, that is what I said you in your last question, why asking again to get the same response? have you checked the mime type the content is being served with? - if you don't know how, please explicitly ask for help about that

Comment: Indeed , i don't know how to check that,can you help ? and am asking the same question but with different ways , this question i thing express clearly the Problem ...

Comment: Thx Ian , but tell me please , can a wrong MIME type affect only internet Explorer and not the other browsers?

Comment: Ah ok, apologies, I missed that it was working on other browsers.

Comment: Different browsers appear to handle incorrect/missing mime-types differently. Chrome appears to handles this OK and "works out" the correct video format (at least in the case above), however, IE9 does not. One thing I do find confusing, however, is in the linked article regarding mime-types, it duplicates the `ogg` and `mp4` extensions in the list of Apache `AddType`s - the later (video) is going to override the former (audio)?

Comment: You can pair multiple MIME types with the same file name extension. The examples given are in full hence it includes all of them.

Comment: @IanDevlin: (Just realised you're the chap who wrote that article! :) But how can that work?! Any one file extension can surely only map to a single MIME type otherwise how can the server know which MIME type to return for a particular file extension? And this is as per the [Apache docs for AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype), "...overriding any mappings that already exist for the same extension". This is what appears to happen in .htaccess; the later directive always wins. The other way round is OK... multiple file extensions for a single MIME type.

Answer (score 1):

The web server is serving the video with an incorrect MIME type. The current MIME type is `video/mpeg` (which is not working on IE9). The MIME Content-Type for MP4 video is defined in [RFC 4337](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4337) - see also the paragraph referring to the specific H.264 encoding, that points to [this ISO rule](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=40890) - and it's `video/mp4`. More about video serving content-types [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video).